# How to disable Firefox Updates with CLI?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, command-line-interface

I have to use Firefox 45 in a Docker Container for Selenium Tests with Java.
I need to disable any automatic Firefox Updates by modifying a file.

Where can I configure this? In prefs.js?

Answer (score 3):

Try below steps :

1.Close Firefox.

2. Navigate to the following location based on your operating system.

   ```
   Windows XP/Vista/7/8/10 – "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\"
   Unix/Linux – "~/.mozilla/"
   Mac OS X – "~/Library/Mozilla/" or "~/Library/Application Support/"
   ```
3. Open the “Profiles” folder.

4.Open the folder that represents the profile you would like to edit. The name of the folder will vary. It is usually a bunch of characters, followed by “.default”.

5.Open the prefs.js file with a text editor like Notepad.
Look for a line that contains app.update.enabled. If it doesn’t exist, add a line for it in the file and set it as desired using these examples:

```
  user_pref("app.update.enabled", true); = Automatic updates enabled
  user_pref("app.update.enabled", false); = Automatic updates disabled
```

Comment: thanks for your solution! it was not clear to me that this entry simply does not exist in some cases. so I will add user_pref("app.update.enabled", false); 

is it somewhere documented that the absence of this entry is a default true?